# Centralizer/Normalizer of global sections of vector bundles on curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, gr.group-theory, algebraic-curves, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a smooth, projective curve of genus at least $2$ over $\mathbb{C}$ and $E$ be a vector bundle on $X$ of rank at least $2$. Given any point $x \in X$, denote by $S_x$ the image  of the natural morphism from $H^0(\mathcal{E}nd(E))$ to $\mathcal{E}nd(E)_x$, where $\mathcal{E}nd(E)_x$ denotes the fiber over $x$ for the vector bundle. We define
$$N_x:=\{\phi \in \mathcal{E}nd(E)_x| \mbox{ for all } s \in S_x \mbox{ there exists } s' \in S_x \mbox{ such that } \phi \circ s = s' \circ \phi\}$$
$$C_x:=\{\phi \in  \mathcal{E}nd(E)_x| \mbox{ for all } s \in S_x, \phi \circ s = s \circ \phi\}.$$
Is there any known condition on $E$ under which, there exists a closed point $x \in X$ such that $N_x$ or $C_x$ is the entire $\mathcal{E}nd(E)_x$?

Any idea or reference regarding this question is most welcome.

Comment: For a simple bundle (for example, stable) $E$, $H^0(\mathcal{E}nd(E))$ is just the scalars, so your condition would be trivially satisfied and you have $C_x=N_x=\mathcal{E}nd(E)_x$.

Comment: @Mohan Thanks, is there any other possibilities?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Mohan meaning, are there examples when $E$ is not simple but gives a positive answer to the question.

Comment: Take $E$ to be the trivial bundle, $\mathcal{O}_X^n$.